# Python - Iterate back in time and look if DataFrame contains a specific Date

Tags: python, loops, date

i want to iterate back in time and check if a df contains some dates.

Here's a practical example:

```
start_date = datetime(2000,1,3)
end_date =datetime(2020,12,31)
index = pd.date_range(start_date, end_date, freq='B')
df = pd.DataFrame({'Date':index})
df

    Date
0   2000-01-03
1   2000-01-04
2   2000-01-05
3   2000-01-06
4   2000-01-07
...     ...
5474    2020-12-25
5475    2020-12-28
5476    2020-12-29
5477    2020-12-30
5478    2020-12-31

5479 rows × 1 columns
```

As an exercise i've tried to run this loop:

```
for date in reversed(pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq = 'B')):
    if df.Date == date:
        print(date)
    else:
        print("No")
```

I always get the error:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that this statement will return Series and not a boolean (True/False), which is why the output is `ambiguous`

```
if df.Date == date
```

Therefore the if condition is unable to determine if this is True or False.

You can do this instead

```
if any(df.Date == date)
```

which should give you the expected result.

This is yet not an optimal way of doing it. The right way of getting all dates in one go is using some vectorised / broadcast method such as `isin`

```
>>> dates = reversed(pd.date_range(start_date,end_date,freq = 'B'))
>>> df.Date.isin(dates)
```

This will give you all the dates contained within the `dates` object. Much more efficiently than looping through every single one of them.